# Can I create a model Class in django dynamically?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database, django-models

So I have a tools/model.py Where I add all the tools that I will be using. The thing is each tool has to be a table its self so I can create more than one tool of each and to link that tool to the project that it is being used in.

*I am using MYSQL database*

For example:

**Tools Table must have:**

- tools_ID
- tools_name
- tools_quantity

now according to the **tools_name** I want to create a model or a table for it.

For example:
If I added ScrewDrivers to the Tools table I want it to create a ScrewDrivers Table automatically, Where all the child tables that inherit from Tools tables has the same structure and can't add ScrewDrivers more than the quantity that is specified in the Tools table.

ScrewDrivers table:

Rows = Quantity in Tools table

- ID
- ScrewDrivers_name
- ScrewDrivers_status (Available or being used in a project)

[image]

Comment: It is possible, but not recommended. With a good model design you should be able to achieve what you want without needing dynamic models.

Comment: What do you recommend me to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ **django-dynamic-model 0.3.0** ].This is a opensource package that allows to create runtime dynamic models. also attaching the documentation link.

https://github.com/rvinzent/django-dynamic-models/wiki/Introduction

Comment: Thank you so much, I think this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Happy to help  :)

Comment: check this one. Looks to be a more simple explanation than the previous. haven't worked hands-on with dynamic models, but this looks useful.  https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels